# Copying symlinked files to usb drive with Thunar

Tags: usb-drive, symbolic-link, thunar

[I posted this to stackexchange several days ago and got no response, so I am trying here.]

I have some *.ts video files recorded by MythTV (on Ubuntu with xfce desktop).  There is a script called mythlink.pl that creates symlinks to these files with human-readable names.  I want to copy these files to a flash drive, preserving the human-readable name.  Two questions about this.  First, when I do this with cp, for example:

```
cp -L filename.ts /media/myname/BE3E-7413
```

it requires root permission.  It's a fresh drive out of the package so it's not been formatted unusually or anything. Is there some way to mount the flash drive as the local user rather than root? I know from searching around that you can chown the flash drive, but I'd prefer not to have to do this every time I plug it in.

Second, I would rather do the copying with Thunar file manager.  It has the same permissions problem, which I assume could be fixed via the answer to the above.  However, it appears from the permissions error message that using cut/paste or drag/drop it does not de-reference the symlink (like the -L switch does on cp) and it would copy the file with the original not-human-readable filename.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found a work-around. After getting the flash drive mounted with adequate permissions, in Thunar select edit > Configure custom actions... then hit the + icon to add a new one.  Give it a name like "Copy symlink to USB", and for the command enter

```
cp -L %f /media/usb
```

(or whatever your mount point is).  Then click the Appearance Conditions tab, check all the options, and close everything out.  Now when you right-click on an item there should be "Copy symlink to USB" in the context menu for the symlink item.

The only drawback of this is that there is no progress indicator for the copy operation.  So for large files you will need to watch your disk LED or check the file size in the window for /media/usb to figure out when it's done.